# 'make install' failed after 'make' KiCad on OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, boost, cmake, kicad

i'm trying to install **kicad** on **osx 10.10**. After successfully build `make`, failed 
`make install` at

```
-- fixup_bundle
--   app='/Users/bolor/Downloads/KiCad/bin/eeschema.app/Contents/MacOS/eeschema'
--   libs=''
--   dirs=''
-- fixup_bundle: preparing...
-- warning: embedded item does not exist '/Users/bolor/Downloads/KiCad/bin/eeschema.app/Contents/MacOS/libboost_chrono-mt.dylib'
-- 
warning: cannot resolve item '@loader_path/libboost_chrono-mt.dylib'

  possible problems:
    need more directories?
    need to use InstallRequiredSystemLibraries?
    run in install tree instead of build tree?

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: can't open file: @loader_path/libboost_chrono-mt.dylib (No such file or directory)
```

**CMake** was configured like below:

`cmake ../kicad \
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ \
    -DCMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.10 \
    -DwxWidgets_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE=../wx-bin/bin/wx-config \
    -DKICAD_SCRIPTING=OFF \
    -DKICAD_SCRIPTING_MODULES=OFF \
    -DKICAD_SCRIPTING_WXPYTHON=OFF \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../bin \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DKICAD_SKIP_BOOST=ON \
    -DCMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk`

does anyone know how to solve this? 
thanks!

i have saved all the build log in a txt file and put on dropbox readable
[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6uxz7n6q0zq8ral/build_log.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Can you check whether CMake emits a warning related to Boost?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that's a bug in kicad's CMake script.

Other have the same problem, see https://gist.github.com/rhaamo/497d3c94929b69874411

In
http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/380428
they say it either works with `-DKICAD_SKIP_BOOST=ON` or with letting kicad build its own Boost library.

Comment: thanks! i agree, CMake does something strange. the posts of the mentioned other forums are mine ^^